# Git commit fails build if no changes, but exit code is still 0

Tags: git, continuous-integration, sh, github-actions

While writing a GitHub action that commits and pushes build artifacts to another repo, I came across weird behavior of `git push` that I don't understand.

This is my build script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status:
set -e

### Creation of artifacts happens here. They are written to ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/output/

echo "Cloning $artifacts_repo ..."
git clone $artifacts_repo "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/artifacts_repo"
echo "DEBUG: exit code of 'git clone' operation:"
echo $?

echo "Moving generated files to ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/artifacts_repo/auto-generated ..."
mkdir -p "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/artifacts_repo/auto-generated"
yes | cp --recursive --force "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/output/." "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/artifacts_repo/auto-generated"

echo "Committing artifacts ..."
cd "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/artifacts_repo"

git status
echo "DEBUG: exit code of 'git status' operation:"
echo $?

git add .
echo "DEBUG: exit code of 'git add' operation:"
echo $?

git commit -m"Auto-generated artifacts"
echo "DEBUG: exit code of 'git commit' operation:"
echo $?

echo "Pushing artifacts ..."
git push
echo "DEBUG: exit code of 'git push' operation:"
echo $?
```

If there are changes to commit, the script runs through successfully. All exit codes are `0`,

If there are **no** changes to commit (because the generated files match those that are already in the repo), the script fails at the `git commit` operation without printing the exit code. Also other exit codes are still `0`.

I have `set -e` enabled to make the build fail at the first non-zero exit code.

If I remove `set -e` to debug this, the script runs through, but even without changes to commit, the exit code of `git commit` is `0`. So why is the build failing then?

This is the output when `set -e` is disabled:

```sh
Cloning https://***@github.com/my-org/my-repo.git ...
Cloning into '/github/workspace/artifacts_repo'...
DEBUG: exit code of 'git clone' operation:
0
Moving generated files to /github/workspace/artifacts_repo/auto-generated ...
Committing artifacts ...
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
DEBUG: exit code of 'git status' operation:
0
DEBUG: exit code of 'git add' operation:
0
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
DEBUG: exit code of 'git commit' operation:
0
Pushing artifacts ...
Everything up-to-date
DEBUG: exit code of 'git push' operation:
0
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? Is something wrong with Git? Has it something to do with the way GitHub actions work (I'm new to those)? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the build exits after `git push` and not after `git commit`? `git commit` will exit with non zero if there is nothing to commit.

Comment: You're right, with 'set -e' enabled it exits after 'git commit'. Sorry for mixing that up. HOWEVER, with 'set -e' disabled, the exit code of 'git commit' is still '0' although nothing was to commit. So it is still very confusing to me :-P

Comment: I added the debug output for 'set -e' disabled with no changes to commit.

Comment: Okay: I'm just to dumb for this stuff :-P The exit code is always 0, because it's the exit code of the previous 'echo' operation *facepalm* Is it good practice to delete stupid questions, or should I rather add a big warning sign?

Comment: I think it is not really dumb...It happens sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git commit -m"Auto-generated artifacts"
echo "DEBUG: exit code of 'git commit' operation:"
echo $?
```

echo $? means the status code of previously executed command. so it means we have executed `echo "DEBUG: exit code of 'git commit' operation:"` so the status code is zero.

When set -e is enabled it monitors every command execution so as soon as git commit gives non-zero code build fails. Same logic goes for all your echo $? statements.

Hope it is clear.

Comment: I realized that myself :-D I was about to delete that question because it is misleading. As your answer correctly points out my mistake, I'll keep it. Thanks for your efforts!